# MuPDF Crash Issue in Signed APk

Tags: crash, mupdf, signed-apk

i have integrated mupdf in my android application and it works flawless in the emulator and device i use but it crashes in release version, after creating signed apk if i click on pdf file to open the app crashes showing the error below

E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no field with name='globals' signature='J' in class Lcom/artifex/mupdflib/MuPDFCore;
                                                          at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFCore.openFile(Native Method)
                                                          at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFCore.(Unknown Source)
                                                          at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity.a(Unknown Source)
                                                          at com.artifex.mupdflib.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5058)
                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2151)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5003)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Is that the *only* error in the log? Can you put a full adb log on pastebin or similar.

Comment: i get this same  errors every time and once i put proguard to false..everything works fine..but i want to use proguard for sure..how to overcome this ..i want to use proguard simultaneously with mupdf .. @JosephH

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
-keep class com.artifex.mupdfdemo.** {*;}
```

to your proguard configuration